# adding new row to existing dataset which already has values

Tags: c#

I have a dataset where I am pulling value from the database, now after that, I want to add some more rows to it. I get four columns from the database: approverName, approverEmail, approverRole, approvalStatus

```
DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();            
dsResult = getDataFromDatabase();           

DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("approverName", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("approverEmail", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("approverRole", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("approvalStatus", typeof(string)));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["approverName"] = "John";
dr["approverEmail"] = "John@gc.com";
dr["approverRole"] = "Manager";
dr["approvalStatus"] = "Pending";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dsResult.Tables.Add(dt);
```

But after executing code I don't see this manually added value in the dataset. It only shows the value which I had after executing line 2 of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create another DataTable.

Append new row to existing DataTable

```
DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();            
dsResult = getDataFromDatabase();           

DataTable dt = dsResult.Tables[0]; //Get Reference to existing table

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["approverName"] = "John";
dr["approverEmail"] = "John@gc.com";
dr["approverRole"] = "Manager";
dr["approvalStatus"] = "Pending";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: is there a way I can add this row at the top of dataset.

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz, Use `dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);` read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat?view=netcore-3.1